# How can I check my ip address?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a login function where I am using user name and password to login. Now I want to check the id address also.My ip addresses are in another table where id is matched with the rank. I need to know how can I check ip in same function of my controller.How can I write my functions ?

```
Ip address table:               login table:

id  ip_address                  ID uname pass      rank
2   98.231.50.890               1  admin admin321   1
```

Here is my login function. There is a filed rank. IF rank is 1. User  can login easily other wise function will check that ip address.

```
public function loginAction() {
        $postArray = $this->input->post();
        $table= 'login';
        //$user_type=1;
        if (!empty($postArray)) {
            $result = $this->m_common->login_with_password_string($postArray['user_name'], $postArray['user_pass'], $table);
            if (!empty($result->ID) && isset($result->ID)) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$result->ID);
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_name',$result->uname);
                $this->session->set_userdata('theme',$result->theme);
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',1);
                //$this->is_logged_in($this->session->userdata('logged_in'));
                redirect(site_url(ADMIN.'/dashboard/view_player'));
//                echo 'Hello';
            } else {

                 $data['message']="Incorrect Username or Password";
                  $this->titlebackend("View Players");
                 $this->load->view('v_login',$data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: how can i implement the condition as i am taking ip address from another table.

Comment: What is the association between the IP(s) in the DB and the user's IP? One user can connect from one IP, there are a series of IPs you allow access from, something else?

Comment: there are a series of ips i have given an sample db table above. login table has a field named rank. rank 1 user can access without ip validation but other users have to pass those range or specific ip addresses.

Comment: Query your DB for allowed IPs. Put them into an array. Use `in_array` and compare against $_SERVER value above. If rank is 1 or it is in the array allow else deny.

Comment: That is how it could be done via PHP and mysql. I havent used codeigniter.

Comment: problem is i am facing difficulties where to put this condition. As i haven't done this before i am in a fix now. you can see i checked user name and password.But now where do i have to put this condition. Can you please re-edit my post. That will be a great help. TIA

Comment: I don't know how to do the querying in codeigniter. I can tell you what your conditional should become if that is what you are looking for; you'll need to populate the IPs array though. I also don't see where the `rank` is checked/set.

Answer (score 2):

> you can use this

`$ip = $this->input->ip_address();
  echo $ip;`

Comment: this will check my ip from ips table??

Comment: No.. u can't  check from table.. its check the system IP only

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 , write an get ip address function like following

```
 function getRealIpAddr(){
  if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  }elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  }else{
      $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
  return $ip;
}
```

Step 2 , Query all ip_address as an array from ip address table

```
$ips = array(); // assume this result from you database
if(in_array($ip,$ips)){
  // true
}
// or you can loop the ips array
foreach(ips as $lip){
  if($lip == $ip){
     //true
     break;
  }
}
```

For you case i suggest you convert ip to long type before stored into database , because it will improve the query performance when ip tables have the large data.

```
$long = ip2long($ip);
```